# Dynamic column name for update query

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, netbeans-8

I'am trying to update table from multiple columns names(lo1,lo2,...) that are to be taken dynamically. But the values are not getting updated in database.
column names are co1,co2....

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
         Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/netbeans","root","");



        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM colo");

    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM colo");
    // get the number of rows from the result set
    rs.next();
    int rowCount = rs.getInt(1); 

     //txt_ans.setText(String.valueOf(rowCount));
     int num_1 =300;
     int num_2 =200;
     int num_3 =300;
     int num_4 =400;
     String value = null;
     int value1 ;

     for(int i=1;i<=rowCount;i++)
     {

        String sql =("SELECT * FROM colo WHERE id = '"+i+"'");

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery(sql);
       while(rs.next())
          value = rs.getString("co1");
       //txt_ans.setText(String.valueOf(value));
       String x = "co2";
       if(value.equals("lo1"))
       {
          // value1= 1;
          // txt_ans.setText(String.valueOf(value1));


             String sql1 =("update colo set '"+x+"' = '"+num_1+"' where id = '"+i+"'");
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
      int r = pstmt.executeUpdate(sql1);


       txt_ans.setText(String.valueOf(r));    

       }
       else if(value.equals("lo2"))
       {
          // value1= 1;
          // txt_ans.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
      String sql1 =("update colo set '"+ x +"' = '"+num_2+"' where id = '"+i+"'");
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
      int r = pstmt.executeUpdate(sql1);


       txt_ans.setText(String.valueOf(r));    

       }
       else
       {
           value1 = 9009;
           txt_ans.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
       }


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with using single quotes for column name i.e, like **'x'**, so just remove them as shown below:

```
String sql1 =("update colo set " + x + " = ? where id = ?");//no single quote for x
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
pstmt.setString(1, num_1);
pstmt.setString(2, i);
int r = pstmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
```

Also, always use `prepareStatement`'s `setString`, etc.. methods for setting the values which is recommended.

Apply the same concept for the other query inside the `else if(value.equals("lo2"))` block as well.

Comment: Still no change @javaguy

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?